# .NET Core - How To Manage User Secrets Within A Team

Tags: .net-core

The [storage of secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows) for .NET Core is well [documented](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2017/09/10/managing-secrets-in-net-core-2-0-apps/).

However, in the .NET Core world, I cannot find a good article on how such information is *shared amongst a team*.

Say, for example, we have a .NET Core Project that has information stored within `secrets.json`and there are 10 developers using that project.

Options I can think of:

1. Check something into source control - seems to defeat the point (apart from not accidentially publishing test settings to live).
2. Just talk between ourselves - has the feeling that if someone adds a secret and goes on holiday, other devs will waste time figuring out what's missing. It might also cause issue if two developers add something around the same time.
3. Ignore `secrets.json` and always use [Azure KeyVault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/key-vault/) - even for dev. More complicated and I haven't seen this recommended anywhere, but it would also work for building on build servers. The downside is that the Vault could get cluttered with unused settings and it not be clear which need replicating in live.

There may be other options I've missed.

What is the best way to share/ synchronise secrets with other developers?

EDIT FOLLOWING ANSWER:

Going the KeyVault route will work. As stated, this requires additional setup (using certificates, for example). Further details in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#secret-storage-in-the-development-environment).

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sniptt-official/snip-cli. Might be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although this is biassed: go for 3, use the key vault.

---

##### Diclaimer

There are many blog-post and documentation on this subject, here I'll address a very narrow portion of the scope of the question.

An alternative recommendation would be or use methodology like GitOps/SOPS as described [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-global/gitops-and-secret-management-with-aks-flux-cd-sops-and-azure-key/ba-p/2280068)

---

As for the Vault option, it has some benefits of which I will name some:

- secrets are stored in a central place, making governance and rotation easier
- secrets are not known to developers, or only at a need to know basis, which makes it more secure
- secrets, if implemented correctly, are no part of the version control, which also makes it more secure.

some con's

- it takes some time to set up properly
- it's less flexible, especially it the process isn't in place yet.
- secrets, if implemented correctly, are no part of the version control, which makes recovery harder.

To elaborate on that last one: there are scenario's where you **need** a "stable" and **recoverable** secret, e.g.: when a client **needs** to integrate in a specific manner, which **require** you to have control over a secret. Although security-wise this is not best practice, it is quite common. A [GitOps/SOPS](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-global/gitops-and-secret-management-with-aks-flux-cd-sops-and-azure-key/ba-p/2280068) is more suited in that scenario.

---

In general, the more developers have access to the secrets, the more insecure it is.

Ideally, if you set it up correctly, you'll end up with the same way of dealing with this across all your environments (test, staging prod). In the end, the solution and process should be independent of the environment, to maximize production stability.

---

But as I said; this is biassed and opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

We opted to store the config in a database [I know, but read on].

The issue for us was not only that config must be shared with multiple developers, but it became cumbersome to switch between environments and update all the values in the secrets.json file accordingly so that they are consistent to the environment that is targeted.

This is to avoid situation where developers are pointing to the DEV database, but still using UAT/STAGING API credentials.

We created a single DB and segregated our Configuration tables into different schemas per environment which allows us to grant developer access to only the schemas they require. In addition, the VALUE of the config setting can still be stored as a KeyVault link, which our provider will pick up and read those sensitive settings from KeyVault.

This reduced our secrets.json to only store the connection string to the Config database, which never changes. We also have an EnvironmentName which is used by the provider to read the config from the corresponding schema configuration table.